# How to set up a server of multiple Django projects that require virtual environments?

Tags: django, deployment, virtual, environment

I currently am renting out a virtual machine through a web hosting service with the intention of hosting a django website on it via IIS. I am planning on hosting multiple django websites on it, all within separate virtual environments. I heard through multiple django tutorials that using django (and other dependencies) within virtual environments is good practice, so I created a virtual environment (virtualenv) on my virtual machine and pip installed django (and mysqlclient for connections to my database within my django website). Locally, this would work fine. All I have to do to get my website to work is to activate my virtual environment by going to my virtual environment's Script directory and passing the parameter "activate", and then change directory to my django project and run manage.py runserver. If I were to skip the step where I activate my virtual environment and instead just run manage.py runserver, I would obviously get an error, because django nor mysqlclient exist globally, but rather only in the virtual environment.

This begs the question: in production, how am I supposed to activate the virtual environments for each Django website, and THEN launch the server? I have only ever found tutorials online that show me how to launch a django website on IIS (see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cgTFrAwXeoI&index=2&t=0s&list=LLgWL_7FtfJwdE6X7zwnAdNQ) , but not when the project is wrapped in a virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [docker](https://www.docker.com/) to you. You can make multiple django containers with `docker` and set virtual environments independent of each container.

Answer (score -1):

Use Pycharm,

You can use a program, to archive this. [Pycharm](http://www.pycharm.com/). They have a community edition that is free, as well as a payed version.

When you set up a project in pycharm, you create a virtualenv on your computer. This viritualenv you can make available to all projects.

[Create a new project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqoZi.png)
Under "project Interpreter" mark the checkbox "Make project available to all projects
then when you create a new projects, select this interpreter Then these two projects share the same interpreter. You can even attach the second project, to the first project, so you can work on them at the same time.

It also have support for docker, and interpreter over ssh. so it can be combined in yongjin-jo answer as well.

Comment: This is not at all an answer to the question., Pycharm is an IDE, it will absolutely not help with deploying on IIS.

Comment: The so-called IDE, does this for him. Everything he ask, can be done done inside pycharm. Both for ISS and docker. (I use docker my self, for this.) pushing the files using ssh.